# can somebody explain me why os.remove doesn't work properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a repository with folders and images inside these folders. The point is that I cant figure out how this method os.remove works. In some folders it removes unneeded files , in some doesn't, also some folders is shrinking in sizes ( 10-15 images ), some isn't. What am I missing here?

```
dirs = next(os.walk(path))[1]

for d in dirs:
    dirPath = path  + d
    os.chdir(dirPath)

    dirPath = path  + d


    files = next(os.walk(dirPath))[2]

    for f in files:
        if f is 'feature.bin': os.remove('feature.bin')      
        if f is 'filelist_LBP.txt': os.remove('filelist_LBP.txt')
        if f is 'info.txt': os.remove('info.txt')
```

Comment: Have you checked that the dirs variable is being set to something? Because if it's the child directory (i.e. with no directories below it) you won't walk through any files

Comment: Also, avoid comparisons using "is" when you mean "==".  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce for more details.

Answer (score 4):

`os.remove` needs the full path to the file to be deleted, unless it happens to be in the current directory.